Creating polygon boundaries in Power BI using Mapbox
I have a geojson file that displays lat/long values for school boundaries. I want to display these on a map in Power BI using Mapbox Visual. 'School' is in the 'Location' field, Lat and Lon values are in their respective fields as well. The points are displaying as dots on the map, but I cannot find a way to connect them.
Photo of the current map is above.
I am hoping to, at the very least, connect the dots to create polygon boundaries. The original geojson contains lat/long values for all school boundaries in lists, organized by school. I want these to display as either filled, or open polygons against a street map, where I can plot student locations to view their proximity to their school's boundary.

Hi, there is no photo/image on the post
